# Is this formula valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

is this formula valid ??, if it is not what interpretation could i use ?

(∀ x: P(x) -> ∀ x: Q(x)) -> ∀ x: (P(x) -> Q(x)).

PS : i know that the other implication is valid.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter? That might help us to tailor our responses to the question.

Comment: i am sure that the formula is not valid , i found topics about that , but i'am unable to find an interpretation to demonstrate its invalidity

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in a book, (Introduction to discrete mathematics 6th Edition  by Elliott Mendelson page 425 ).

Assume this interpretation : the domain is N , P(x) means x is even , Q(x) means x is odd. The hypothesis is always true ( False implies False) but the Goal is always false (x even implies w odd) which is absurd.

[image]